# Looping through all sites, lists, items with minimal call

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom

I've built a function/object using SPSservices to retrieve all sites in 1 collection, go through each site to find the Document Libraries, then for each document library return all items which have `CheckedOutTo != null`.

Essentially I'm creating a report of all checked out documents in a collection. It works great, except, the number of web calls is dependent on the size of the collection. It's a great way to crash the browser if the collection is large enough.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to bring this function over to CSOM/JSOM and do all the heavy lifting server side?

I haven't used CSOM/JSOM much so this question doesn't have any code but if anyone has any examples or recommendations that'd be useful.

Comment: Have you looked at the possibility to use Search and the `ows_q_USER_CheckoutUser` prop instead? That should speed up the time a lot if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all files in a collection using Search api or JSOM